# How can I use contingency table, and fisher test in R, given counts

Tags: r, testing, datatable, tibble, contingency

I know table() creates a table of two categorical variables from the data by counting. But my issue is that I am already given a table. [image: Table]

I am supposed to test whether flower color affects color survivorship using chisq.test() and fisher.test(). If i create a tibble

```
color_tibble <- tibble(
White = c(143, 130),
Light = c(184, 100),
Dark = c(176, 107) )                              

chisq.test(color_tibble$White)
```

That works to conduct chisq tests for all three colors, but I would not be able to use the fisher test because it is not an actual contingency table, nor are there two categorical variables to compare. I have no actual data set/frame to create a table using table().

Ideally I would like to compare the categorical variables "color" with values white/light/dark and "survivorship" values survived/dead.

hopefully this makes sense to you

Comment: Also it should be fairly stright forward to create the source data: `rbind( data.frame(color="White",result=c(rep( "Survived",143), rep("Died",130))), data.frame(color="Light",result=c(rep( "Survived",184), rep("Died",100))), data.frame(color="Dark",result=c(rep( "Survived",176), rep("Died",107))) )`. Run `table()` on that and you get what you have. Though completely unecessary as chisq.test and fisher.test happily work on ready made tables like you have

Answer (score 1):

I think `chisq.test` works on matrices.  Do like this

```
M <- as.matrix(color_tibble)
dimnames(M) <- list(survivorship = c("survived", "died"),
                    colors = c("White", "Light", "Dark"))
M

chisq.test(M)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  M
X-squared = 9.8681, df = 2, p-value = 0.007197

fisher.test(M)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  M
p-value = 0.007558
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```